# Do I need to keep "recompiling" my iPhone app code everytime apple releases a new iOS version?

Tags: iphone

New here guys but have got a genuine problem. I have an iPhone app that was developed using SDK4. With apple introducing the new iOS version 6, does my code need to be recompiled on the new SDK to make it compatible with version 6?

Right now it crashes on iOS6. Also, do I need to do that everytime apple brings out a new version? I wonder every other app on earth already does that ?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with major iOS upgrades is method deprecation. It may happen that some parts of your code relies on methods that are not supported in iOS6. When this happens you should first check for API changes then recompile it with the latest API. If your code base works fine with iOS6 than there is no need for recompiling it, but unfortunately that doesn't seems to be your case.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't need too. Most of the time, Apple publishes updates for libraries, so sometimes the old code is not compatible anymore. You have to recompile it, or you'll find issues.

For example I had a working app on iOS 5. With the iOS 6 update, I had to refer some code new because the app crashed with SIGABRT. Before iOS 6 it was working fine. Through Xcode's Debugger, most of the time finding issues is not hard work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that most of the time a crash will be caused by an existing bug in my application that I wasn't aware of. Subtle changes revealed it. It is rarely just a question of recompiling, but of fixing that bug.

Just recompiling can be dangerous. Apple can (and does) detect what version of the development tools your app was compiled with, maintains some behaviour that will keep your app running. Update, and you'll get the new behaviour instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to recompile mine just for the sake of IOS6. They worked fine. But I had to adjust for 4" iphone 5 screen.